# How do I deal with a coworker who keeps making racist comments?

Tags: racial-issues

I had a former co worker say something I was offended by. (I’m African American and he’s Caucasian.)

I told him to be careful wiping down the mantle over a fireplace because it was hot and I didn’t want him to get burnt. He proceeded to wipe it off, looked over at me and said "well at least if you get burnt they won’t be able to see it" and kept walking.  I was speechless an sick to my stomach. I let my manager know. They talked to him and he was never disciplined for it at all. He apologized and said he would never talk to me again, which I said ok, thank you.

A couple days after that he said "how are you doing, Janet Jackson?" I already felt uncomfortable working with him. I informed my manager again they talked to him and he continued to work there.

Should I have done something different?

Comment: Welcome to Interpersonal.SE! Just to clarify, you're asking us whether you could have handled your coworker's racist comments better? Did you tell your coworker directly that he was being racist?

Comment: This isn't an interpersonal issue but an HR issue. The other employee certainly has earned more than a reprimand or talking-to. Post it on Workplace SE. They may be able to help you get around an ineffective manager.

Comment: Hi Lynette, as explained in the on hold banner, we require questions here to have a specific goal. "What should I have done?" is impossible for us to answer without knowing what successfully "dealing with" the coworker means to you. If you can [edit] your post with a specific goal, it will be placed in a queue where community members can vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 3):

Reporting the incident to your manager was the correct thing to do. Not escalating the situation was the correct thing to do.

Every time he says something racist, report it to your manager. If you feel your manager is not doing anything, go to HR and report it to them. It is important that there is a paper trail that explains what happened and how you responded and how others did not respond. (HR won't do anything, but the paper trail is important)

Beyond that, it gets difficult. However this question will likely get closed, so wazawazawoozle.

Comment: Interesting. "Every time he says something, report it to your manager". Does that include "Good morning"?

Comment: @gnasher729 lol, something racist ofc

Comment: Then you should write that in your answer. Because it sounds as if you tell her to hound him down. Opens his mouth, gets reported to HR.

Answer (score -1):

Going by your two quotes, this seems to be an individual who tries to be funny but fails miserable, and who isn't very good with words. You were offended. Do you think he intended to offend you, or is this something that can be explained with verbal clumsiness? Some people come out with the stupidest things all the time.

I would generally recommend to expect the best from people, if they say something that *might* be offensive give them the benefit of the doubt, don't take things to heart because you never know how it was really meant, and get along with people. And when you learn that this was wrong, that he is indeed trying to insult you or worse (which might be due to race, or sexism, or he might just be an a**hole who doesn't like your face), then come down on him like a hammer.

But whatever happens, don't let it affect you. If he insults you, you should feel anger with him, not be affected by it yourself. An insult towards you doesn't mean there is anything wrong with you, it means there's something wrong with him. If something similar happens, tell yourself "I'm fine, he's the one with the problem". You will feel better for it.

It's easy to say in hindsight, and much more difficult when you are in the situation unprepared, but when he said  "well at least if you get burnt they won’t be able to see it", the best reaction would have been to say "what do you mean by that?". The answer would have given you a much better understanding of the situation. He could have said "I think that came out wrong, what I really meant was (something totally harmless)", or he could have said something totally racist. But either way, the situation would have been much clearer. As I said, much easier to say in hindsight.